# phonegap events in backbone js application

Tags: backbone.js, cordova

I am looking for a way to constantly check if my backbone application is online or offline (in the iPad). Currently I am able to do that only in the main.js. Looks like the events are not triggered when I move away from the first page.
How can I have the same events stay alive through all my views?

Just so I am clear,
In Backbone JS, my first script to be executed is the main.js script (using require js).
I'm adding evenlisteners to listen to the device being ONLINE and OFFLINE.

I am using a HOMEVIEW when the router finds no hashtags in the URL.

In the HOMEVIEW, since thats the first time main.js gets executed, the ONLINE / OFFLINE detection of the device status works.

But when I go to another VIEW (using router), the ONLINE / OFFLINE events are not working anymore.

I want the ONLINE / OFFLINE detection to work across my whole application and not just the first time the app loads.

Comment: You're probably going to need to clarify *which* events you're referring to in order for anyone to help.  Also "main.js" without context doesn't mean much.  You said that events aren't triggered when you change pages, but do those new pages have main.js on them?  Or by "pages" do you really mean Backbone routes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about require.js, but couldn't the issue be that you attach the window event to a function inside your main.js that is not accessible from other views?
Where is the function you call for those events, are they anonymous functions or functions of main.js?

I have a backbone+phonegap project without require and have no issue with online/offline in any of my views.

Comment: They are functions of the main.js script. The main.js is called only once when the application first loads. How have you put this function? Do you have the js file (containing this function) included in your index.html?

Comment: yes js file included in html file. listener initiated in the ondeviceready and the function is in a global object. Maybe you could try to put your functions in the window object?